# @font-face linking with gotham condensed not working

Tags: css, font-face

Im trying to link Gotham font files to my page but i cant make it work! Am i missing something? These is the css im using:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Gotham Condensed';
src: url('Gotham/GothamCond-Black.otf')  format('opentype');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenType font format should work in most browsers - however, in Internet Explorer (all versions) it won't work if the "Permission" in the File Explorer settings is not set to "Installable" ([look here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf)). There's the font authors who set this setting, and it's hard to change it - as it is regarding copyright stuff. Some software do it, however - but I've had some issues with it.

The best thing you could do is to use a font converter online to convert it to the WOFF format (works in all modern browsers) and the EOT format, if you need to support IE 8 and older. These font formats does not contain copyright information like OTF files does, so it should work. You should also consider converting to the SVG and TTF font formats to support even more old browsers.

The FontSquirrel generator posted over here won't work on Gotham, because it's a commercial font, and you need a webfont license for that. Use a font convertor.

Comment: All ready tried converting the file! Do you consider de css to be fine?

Comment: @MarianoUrbonas Yes, the CSS seems fine. Try [this](http://www.freefontconverter.com/) website, and convert it to WOFF. Then upload it to your site, and change the source in the CSS. Also change the format to "woff". You could also try double brackets ("") instead of single brackets ('') on everything. If it's not working at this point, it's not longer a problem with your code, but it could be with the server or another problem.

Comment: Now its ok! I was missing the `body{font-family:'Gotham Condensed'; }`!!! Thanks @SimenMangseth for the help!!

Comment: @MarianoUrbonas You're welcome! I thought you already had that in the `body` - because that line is definitely crucial. Let me know if you have any other problems with HTML and CSS, I'd be glad to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use web font generator: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator